# How to clear all items from an AnimatedList in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animatedlist

I was trying to preproduce all of the update operations on an AnimatedList like I have done for a RecyclerView adapter in Android. But when I got to clearing all of the data, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

If I do this

```
setState(() {
  _data.clear();
});
```

then the backing data is cleared but the GlobalKey's current state still doesn't know about the change, and there is no `clear()` method on it.

Supplemental code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Update AnimatedList data')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyWidgetState createState() {
    return new BodyWidgetState();
  }
}

class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {

  // the GlobalKey is needed to animate the list
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  // backing data
  List<String> _data = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: AnimatedList(
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: _data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
              return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
            },
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            'Clear all items',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _clearAllItems();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _clearAllItems() {
    _data.clear();
    // no such method
    _listKey.currentState.clear();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to remove item in `_listKey.currentState` manually

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Update AnimatedList data')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyWidgetState createState() {
    return new BodyWidgetState();
  }
}

class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {
  // the GlobalKey is needed to animate the list
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  // backing data
  List<String> _data = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: AnimatedList(
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: _data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
              return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
            },
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            'Clear all items',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _clearAllItems();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _clearAllItems() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= _data.length - 1; i++) {
      _listKey.currentState.removeItem(0,
          (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
        return Container();
      });
    }
    _data.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Is there anything better than this today?

Answer (score 13):

Every time you pass new key to `AnimatedList` widget, it will recreate its state and rebuild next time with a brand new list of items:

```
var _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

void _clearAllItems() {
  _data.clear();
  setState(() => _listKey = GlobalKey());
}
```

Comment: The accepted solution is probably "more correct" in that it will animate the changes; however, this worked well for my use case (updating the list after the user input a search query). I also needed a solution to reload the list after events triggered elsewhere in the app, without iterating old and new lists and recording the differences. For these cases, this solution works well.

Comment: Clean and good solution. Should give people insight into how keys work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is way simpler.

```dart
    _listKey.currentState
                  ?.removeAllItems((context, animation) => const SizedBox.shrink());
```