# How to use AnimatedList Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I saw this [video on youtube](https://youtu.be/ZtfItHwFlZ8)

and I'm trying to implement an animated list,

but I'm not really familiar with animations.

What I'm supposed to insert as

> position: animation.drive(),

and

> removeItem(_index,(context,animation)=>  /// what I'm supposed to do
>   here
>       ),);

here's the code (just few changes from the "starting app")

```
      class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<int> _list = [];
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();


  void _addItem() {
    final int _index = _list.length;
    _list.insert(_index,_index);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(_index);
  }

  void _removeItem() {
    final int _index = _list.length-1;
    _listKey.currentState.removeItem(_index,(context,animation)=>  /// what I'm supposed to do here
    ),);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: AnimatedList(
          key: _listKey,
          initialItemCount: 0,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
            return SlideTransition(
              position: animation.drive(
                  /// what I'm supposed to do here
           ),
              child: Card(child: Text(_list[index].toString()),));
          },),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(children: <Widget>[
         FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed:()=> _addItem(),
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: ()=>_removeItem(),
          tooltip: 'Decrement',
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),),
      ],), 
    );
  }
}
```

looking around for tutorial on SliderTransition I see this:

```
SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
```

while I have this:

```
 SlideTransition(
                  position: animation.drive(
                      // what i supposed to go here ??
                  ),
```

can anybody help?

is it only this missing piece or I'm missing something else?

thank you in advance

[edit: the [AnimatedList page](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list)  shows the message

> This page is deprecated and its content may be out of date.

in fact doesn't seems to use this widget at all]

Comment: e.g code - https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list

Comment: "This page is deprecated and its content may be out of date." (in fact the do not use the animatedList widget, they just call a widget that way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376474/how-to-clear-all-items-from-an-animatedlist-in-flutter)

you can find my code [--> HERE <--](https://github.com/iapicca/animated_list_demo)

and below

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<int> _list = [];
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();


  void _addItem() {
    final int _index = _list.length;
    _list.insert(_index,_index);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(_index);
  }

  void _removeItem() {
    final int _index = _list.length-1;
    _listKey.currentState.removeItem(_index,(context,animation)=> Container()); /// what I'm supposed to do here
    _list.removeAt(_index);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: AnimatedList(
          key: _listKey,
          initialItemCount: 0,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
            return _buildItem(_list[index].toString(),animation);
          },),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed:()=> _addItem(),
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: ()=>_removeItem(),
            tooltip: 'Decrement',
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),),
        ],),
      ],), 
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String _item, Animation _animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: _animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            _item,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```